# How to convert List<object> to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ienumerable

How do I return `expected` as `IEnumerable<T>` given the code below?

```
public List<object> expected = new List<object>();

public IEnumerable<T> SqlQuery<T>(string sql)
{
    // Return expected as IEnumerable<T>
}
```

(This is a class that was created for unit tests to mock the Entity Framework `SqlQuery<T>` method. We can set our expected result ahead of time and simply have it return what you would expect.)

Comment: Why is `expected` a field and not a local variable of type `List<T>`?

Comment: @MichaelLiu This is a class that was created for Unit tests to Mock the EF SqlQuery Class. We can set our expected result ahead of time and simply have it return what you would expect.

Comment: `return expected.Select(e => e.Cast<T>());` ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  Why are you using a `List<object>` in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that `expected` really contains instances of type `T`, you can use the LINQ [Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) operator:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SqlQuery<T>(string sql)
{
    return expected.Cast<T>();
}
```

InvalidCastException will be thrown if the cast fails for any element.

Comment: If really then why not using `OfType` that will be more safety?

Comment: @VadimMartynov: I think it's better to blow up if there's a bug in the unit test, rather than silently ignoring bad elements.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a list that contains many sub types and you only want to return a specific sub type, you can also do:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SqlQuery<T>(string sql)
{
    return expected.OfType<T>();
}
```

In this case, say you have a `Person` class that is a base class for `Cops` and `Robbers`.

If you'd like all "people" from your collection, you can write: `OfType<Person>`

But if you only wanted the robbers from the collection, use `OfType<Robbers>`

If you ask for a type that doesn't exist in the `expected` collection like `OfType<Footballer>`, an empty collection will be returned.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use LINQ Cast operator to convert to desired IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable<T> SqlQuery<T>(string sql)
{
return expected.Cast<T>();
}
```